# Enclosure and pcb ground

Tags: rf

I'm designing a pcb which contains HF circuits and mounting this in a conducting enclosure.

To minimize EMI/EMC should the pcb ground always be connected to the enclosure?

Or is this not always the way to go?

Comment: what kind of high frequency are we discussion? What size circuit?

Comment: Rf circuit up to 2GHz. Small board 5x10cm.

Comment: To answer your question: yes. There are a lot of options for connecting your ground to the chassis, however. Have a read at [this article](http://www.compliance-club.com/Article.aspx?artid=90) by Keith Armstrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should worry about is proper grounding on the board.  Think about the high frequency current loops carefully.  Keep them small and off the master ground plane.  A shield should be considered the last resort for EMI problems.  It's better to not make a mess in the first place than to try to clean it up afterwards.

If you do have to use a shield, it should be tied to the master ground in *one place only*.  Also keep in mind that every opening in the shield becomes a slot antenna.